# Angular ActivatedRoute data returns an empty object

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

I have a route registered with some data:

```js
const routes: Routes = 
[
    {path: 'my-route', data: { title: 'MyTitle' }, component: MyComponent},
];
```

and I'm trying to access to the route's data using `ActivatedRoute`:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({...})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  private routeData;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.routeData = this.route.data.subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(data); // this is returning an empty object {}
    });
  }
}
```

but for some reasons `data` is an empty object.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: did you try this.route.snapshot

Comment: yes, same result (empty object)

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57447329/5366641

Answer (score 142, accepted):

#### Edit: the problem is that I was trying to access the ActivatedRoute from a Component which is *outside* the `<router-outlet>`. So it looks like that this is the intended behaviour.

However I still think that my answer below can be useful to anyone who is trying to accomplish the same thing.

---

I found a workaround on GitHub (thanks *manklu*) that I used in order to accomplish what I needed:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, RoutesRecognized } from '@angular/router';

@Component({...})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  private routeData;

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events.subscribe((data) => {
      if (data instanceof RoutesRecognized) {
        this.routeData = data.state.root.firstChild.data;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

doing this way `this.routeData` will hold the route data that I needed (in my case the page `title`).

Comment: Hey, where is your github link? I only found this bug report: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19420 :)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Thank you for providing this explanation. I was only calling a specific component via app.component.html - not the `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`. Cheers!

Comment: struggled with this for a while, your solution worked perfectly. thanks

Comment: If you want to get url params instead of your own data use this: `this.router.events.subscribe(val => {
        if (val instanceof RoutesRecognized) {
            var strId = val.state.root.firstChild.params["id"];
        }});`

Comment: For those with data that is nested deeper, this answer worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49632700/64279

Comment: This solved my problem.. and by that I mean I forgot to add a router-outlet... I was going crazy. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Get route custom data for component outside **<router-outlet>** (**Angular 8**):

```js
constructor(private router: Router) {}
    
ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events.subscribe(data => {
      if (data instanceof ActivationStart) {
        console.log(`Custom data`, data.snapshot.data);
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: It worked for me in angular 10. I am trying to capture title key under data object in child component which declared in primary router outlet from appComponent.

Comment: Only works on navigation, not on page load on Angular 12

Comment: Yes this is the Solution if you're getting data To a component that is OUTSIDE <router-outlet>

Comment: @squirtgun works on page load too, test on angular 16

Answer (score 4):

I Don't know the version spoken, but as of **Angular 6**,
this worked for me:

(Ofcourse thanks to shinDath)

```
  routeData;
  ngOnInit() {
    //child route param doesnt go up to parent route params.
    this.router.events.subscribe((val) => {
      if (val instanceof ActivationEnd) {
        if(!$.isEmptyObject(val.snapshot.params)){
          this.routeData = val.snapshot.params;
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: The data that the OP was trying to get was the one defined in the route configuration. This is not what is asked for

Answer (score 3):

### 2024 Update: Get route custom data for component outside `<router-outlet>` (Angular 17+)

This solution is inspired by [Brandon Roberts' solution](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11812#issuecomment-325228258) and updated for Angular 17 (Signals) and RxJS 7.

#### app.component.ts

```js
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common'
import { Component, DestroyRef, OnInit, inject, signal } from '@angular/core'
import { takeUntilDestroyed } from '@angular/core/rxjs-interop'
import { ActivatedRoute, NavigationEnd, Router, RouterModule } from '@angular/router'
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs'
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators'
import { LeftNavComponent } from './core/left-nav/left-nav.component'
import { RouteData } from './route-data'

@Component({
  standalone: true,
  imports: [LeftNavComponent, RouterModule, CommonModule],
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  hideNav = signal(false)
  private readonly destroyRef = inject(DestroyRef)

  constructor(private readonly router: Router, private readonly activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.router.events.pipe(
      takeUntilDestroyed(this.destroyRef),
      filter(e => e instanceof NavigationEnd),
      switchMap(() => this.activatedRoute.firstChild ? this.activatedRoute.firstChild.data : this.activatedRoute.data),
    ).subscribe((data: RouteData) => {
      this.hideNav.set(data.hideNav || false)
    })
  }
}
```

#### app.component.html

```html
<div class="app-container">

  <main class="main-content">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </main>

  @if (!hideNav()) {
    <right-nav class="right-nav"></right-nav>
  }

</div>
```

#### route-data.ts

Helper interface for typed `data`.

```js
export interface RouteData {
  hideNav?: boolean
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is part of my code (NOTE: I'm using **Angular 8**):

```
constructor(private _router: Router, private _route: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit() {
  ...
  this.listenRouting();
}

listenRouting() {
    this._router.events.subscribe((router: any) => {
      routerUrl = router.url;
      if (routerUrl && typeof routerUrl === 'string') {
        routerList = routerUrl.slice(1).split('/');
        console.log("data.breadcrumbs", this._route.snapshot.routeConfig.children.find(child => child.path === routerList[routerList.length - 1]).data.breadcrumbs);
        ...
      }
    });
}
```

So **data** is "hiding" under ActivatedRoute.snapshot.routeConfig.children Array. Each child contains, among other things, **data**.
In my case **data** is configured in routing.module, e.g.:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "facility-datas",
    component: FacilityTerminal,
    data: {
      breadcrumbs: "b ft"
    }
  },
...
];
```

Comment: `ActivatedRoute.snapshot.routeConfig.children` is empty.

Answer (score 2):

Answer from Angular contributor, [link](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11812#issuecomment-325228258)

```
this.router.events.pipe(
    filter((e) => e instanceof NavigationEnd),
    map(() => {
        let route = this.activatedRoute;

        while (route.firstChild) {
            route = route.firstChild;
        }

        return route;
    }),
    filter((route) => route.outlet === 'primary'),
    mergeMap((route) => route.data),
    tap(console.log)
);
```

```
constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
) {}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component} from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-users',
  templateUrl: './users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users.component.scss']
})
export class UsersComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  paramId: string;

  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.paramId = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params.id;
    console.log('paramId =', this.paramId);
  }

}
```

Comment: This will cause ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError exception

Answer (score -9):

Below should work:

```js
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.route.snapshot.data);
}
```