# Load component without root Component in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I am starting learning angular 6. I have a situation where i want to show page with different html without using header and footer. I have added in app.component.html file :

```
<app-header></app-header>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

Now I want to load component without using root component.

Answer (score 0):

Well, You must create a router, here is an example:

In app.module.ts, add:

```
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'crisis-center', component: CrisisListComponent },
  { path: 'hero/:id',      component: HeroDetailComponent },
  {
    path: 'heroes',
    component: HeroListComponent,
    data: { title: 'Heroes List' }
  },
  { path: '',
    redirectTo: '/heroes',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      appRoutes,
      { enableTracing: true } // <-- debugging purposes only
    )
    // other imports here
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And in your app.component.html you have `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` and this is place where angular inject components through router, so remove header and footer and put them into the pages(components) you need to appear.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use "ng-template" for this;

Firstly create a routing module like this;

```
const routes: Routes = [

    { 
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent,
    data: { showRootComponents: false } 
    },
    { 
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent,
    data: { showRootComponents: true } 
    }

]

export const AppRoutingModule = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

And import this in to your AppModule;

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  HomeComponent,
  LoginComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule   
  ]
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Then in your root component;

```
withoutRootComponents:boolean

public constructor(private activatedRoute:ActivatedRoute) {
    this.withoutRootComponents = activatedRoute.snapshot.data['showRootComponents']);
}
```

and html;

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="!withoutRootComponents">
   <app-header></app-header>
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
   <app-footer></app-footer>
</ng-template>

<ng-template [ngIf]="withoutRootComponents">
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: As described here this won't work for the OP as the root component won't get the data from route since it is the one that contains the router-outlet https://stackoverflow.com/a/45737376/186212