# ActivatedRoute is showing null

Tags: angular, angular-activatedroute

trying to get the data from router in different component. 
but its showing `{}` value.

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
{
  path: '',
  loadChildren: './pages/pages.module#PagesModule',  
},
```

**pages-routing.module.ts**

```
path: 'namescan',
        component: NamescanComponent,
        data: { title: 'Name Title' }
```

**header.component.ts**

```
private routeData;
constructor(public router: Router, public activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {    
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe(data => console.log(data.title));    
}
```

even find the smiliar question and even try to update the code but still not working 
[Angular ActivatedRoute data returns an empty object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45737375/angular-activatedroute-data-returns-an-empty-object)

any idea, how to get the data value from router. TIA

Answer (score 1):

you can use `activatedRoute.snapshot.data` so it should look like

```
constructor(activatedRoute:ActivatedRoute) 

ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.data);
  }
```

Comment: `{ }` empty object

Comment: never use the snapshot, it removes the dynamic aspect of your router

Comment: @Maryannah I was thinking of same solution as of yours but I thought if data static and never going to change then  `route.data.subscribe` will create a subscription that will need to unsubscribe later on else may result in memory leak

Comment: That's true about the memory leak ! I'm removing my downvote and upvoting instead, didn't think of that aspect for newcomers

Comment: (Sorry for the edit while I'm at it, my downvote was too old to be removed, had to edit your answer to change it)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the simple & efficient way ?

```js
constructor(route: ActivatedRoute) {
  route.data.subscribe(data => console.log(data.title));
}
```

Comment: @FaisalJanjua then please provide a [mcve] reproducing it

Comment: @FaisalJanjua update it with a [mcve] (actually click on the link to se what it is) provided on, for instance, https://stackblitz.com

Comment: @FaisalJanjua here it is, working : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9t8s3v?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts. Do the same to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Actually at my side its huge application, trying to get on the stackblitz.... quick question, I am using **app-routing.module.ts**  `loadChildren: './pages/pages.module#PagesModule',` and all the routes are in other `routing` file.

Comment: @FaisalJanjua that's why it's called **minimal**, because you only *reproduce* the issue, you don't actually put your whole code ... And again, provide the [mcve] and I'll tell you what's the issue, I gave you everything I could here !